# Any display manager other than gdm boots me into a black screen

Tags: xubuntu, display, gdm

Xubuntu 16.04 user here. I've tried many displays managers (lightdm, sddm, lxdm, slim, Xdm) and all of them boot me into a black desktop, an X shaped cursosr, and firefox lauching by its own means. The only one that works is gdm. Why not keep using it then? because it's hard to configure and I don't like how it looks, also because I like to try different things.

Any idea what could be wrong?

TIA

Gal.-

Comment: Did you reinstall just display manager or the whole gui-interface? Why don't you `sudo apt install --reinstall xdm && sudo apt install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop`? I use Lubuntu, in my laptop, lxdm is not even installed. Lubuntu adopted lightdm as default display manager.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Yes, I did that but the result is the same :(. The default on my distro was lightdm as well, but then it stopped working and that's when I started trying different displays managers with no luck (until gdm).

Comment: I thought you have to purge lightdm after to reinstall xdm. Maybe having conflict among them, but [look this page](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349180), someone found a solution to it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a conflict since the problem started when I just had lightdm as display manager-which was the default that came with the distro-, and after the problem that's when I started to try other dm's (I just purged every dm, and reinstalled lightdm just to make sure but the problem persist)

Comment: By mistake i linked a bbs.archlinux page, after that I correct it, replacing with a Ubuntuforums page. Do you read found solution on this last one?

Comment: Yes, I saw the Ubuntuforums link. Sadly no, it didn't work for me :(